# Does my Debug.WriteLines show up someplace?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, debugging

Here and there in my silverlight application I'm doing Debug.WriteLine. I've deployed the solution to another server, but something is wrong (works locally), is the debugs stored somewhere?

Comment: Debug.WriteLine normally goes to the VS Output window. Silverlight runs in the browser. Is your Debug Output in the Silverlight app or in the serverside code?

Answer (score 0):

Debug.WriteLine internally uses [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which sends output to the currently attached debugger. If you opened browser with URL to remote server, it would load remote Silverlight application and you could [attach Visual Studio debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694624%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the browser afterwards (if dll binaries match).